# Setting a Bootstrap 3 modal title dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the same modal dialog for three different buttons.

However, depending upon which button is clicked, I need to dynamically set the **title** of the modal dialog.

I thought this would be simple setting the title in the appropriate javascript function using jQuery. However, when debugging, I can see the title **is set accordingly in the code**, but **after the modal is displayed**, the modal title is **blank**.

**How can I properly display the modal title accordingly?**

### Here is the pertinent part of the HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="btnJournalVoucherEditGrid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label" aria-hidden="true">


<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label"></h4>
```

### Here is the JS

```
function onEditJournalVoucher(gdId, rwID)
{
  $('#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label').val("Edit Journal Voucher")
```

Answer (score 15):

Well, you're trying to use `.val()` on an H4 tag. Should it not be:

```
$('#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label').text("Edit Journal Voucher");
```

or

```
$('#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label').html("Edit Journal Voucher");
```

`.val()` is the right mindset, but what it does in JQuery is why it won't work in this situation. Take an element that has a `value="something"` attribute, for example:

```
<input id="example" type="text" name="something" value="something"/>
```

Targeting this id using `$("#example")` and calling `.val()` can access or change the `value="something"` attribute. Now take a look at a `<label>` element:

```
<label id="example"> This is some text </label>
```

Notice the lack of a `value="something"` attribute? In this case, since "This is some text" is simply plain-text, using:

```
$("#example").text("Updated Text");
```

is the correct way to go about this. Hope that helps clear things up!

Answer (score 6):

`.val()` is used for form elements (like inputs, checkboxes, etc.)

For divs/other elements (e.g. h4 in your situation) use either `.text()` or `.html()` depending on the situation you want to do.
In this case since this is just text change your line to:

```
$('#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label').text("Edit Journal Voucher");
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you who answered... That just completely slipped my mind. I gave you all a point for it.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
function onEditJournalVoucher(gdId, rwID)
{
    $('#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label').html("Edit Journal Voucher")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **text()** function instead of **val()**:

```
$('#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label').text("Edit Journal Voucher")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the title in the button:

```
<button id="edit-journal-voucher" data-title="Edit Journal Voucher" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid">Edit this Journal</button>
```

Then in the JS do something like:

```
$("#edit-journal-voucher").on("click", funtion(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var title = $(this).data('title');
  $("h4#btnJournalVoucherEditGrid-label").html(title);
});
```